# lua 5.4 __close and collectgarbage causes crash

Tags: lua

I have Lua 5.4 *embedded in a project* and implemented `__close` metamethod for a userdata, which is a vector of numbers. The project has its own script editor and is able to run the scripts. The implementation of `__close` is exactly the same as `__gc` metamethod, which is shown below:

```
int Vector_gc(lua_State* L)
{
    CVector<double>* vector = *(CVector<double>**)lua_touserdata(L, 1);

    delete vector;

    return 0;
}
```

**1)** In a script file, when running the following script, there is no problem at all:

```
local vector=std.rand(5000) --generate 5000 random numbers
vector=nil

collectgarbage()
```

**2)** Similarly, if I run the following script file more than once, again no problem at all:

```
local vector <close> = std.rand(5000)
```

**3)** However, the following script using `collectgarbage` when run more than once causes crash:

```
local vector <close> = std.rand(5000)

collectgarbage()
```

**EDIT 1:**

**4)** The following causes an immediate crash.

```
if(true) then
    local vector <close> = std.rand(5000)
    vector[2]=1
end

collectgarbage()
```

Am I misunderstanding/missing something about to-be-closed variables?

Comment: `__gc/__close` must be idempotent (to avoid deleting the same vector twice: first time in `__close`, second time in `__gc`)

Comment: so basically, we should not call `collectgarbage()` if we are using `<close>`. But how does the garbage collector provides safety if we use closed-variable?

Comment: `__close` is unsafe (it doesn't strictly follow the expected logic).  It might be called 0, 1 or 2 times.  After that `__gc` might be called 0 or 1 times.  So, your function (shared between `__close` and `__gc`) must survive multiple invocations without crashing.

Comment: If it is unsafe, is it then best not to use `<close>` at all, brings confusion...? I tried `collectgarbage("generational")` for the 3rd and 4th cases. For 3rd case it seems to work but for 4th one no luck.

Comment: Making a GC collection step is very slow.  Actually, the only acceptable way is to declare variable as `<close>` and use the same idempotent function for both `__gc` and `__close`.  "Idempotent" means "surviving multiple invocations".

Comment: I found this on a discussion board "You generally want to use <close> for resources other than memory where waiting for garbage collection may be too long. " So for my case maybe `<close>` should just clear the contents of the Vector or do nothing at all.

Comment: Yes, `<close>` is made for fast release of valuable limited resources (file handlers, DB connections, etc.)