# Why does Lua have both `__gc` and `__close`?

Tags: lua, garbage-collection

The Lua manual states that the `__close` metamethod is used when to-be-closed variables go out of scope, and should release the variable's resources. But it also says that when a value is garbage-collected, the `__gc` metamethod is used to release resources.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63535158/lua-5-4-close-and-collectgarbage-causes-crash) one of the comments says that if you have `__close` (or both `__close` and `__gc`) you have to be careful to avoid freeing the memory twice.

I'm still a little confused, though. So long as you're careful about how you write it, why can't there just be a single `__gc` function that gets used in both cases?

Comment: `__gc` is invoked sometime in the future, while `__close` is invoked as soon as possible.  `__close` can be invoked 0,1 or 2 times, so you should write your code so that it would survive the second invocation.

Comment: But why have two separate functions? Wouldn't it be simpler to just write one `__gc` function (being careful to tolerate multiple calls) and use it in both cases? Or to put it differently, is there any situation where you might want `__close` to do something different from `__gc`?

Comment: `__close` is called when the object goes out of scope. This may happen multiple times, if there are many variables that refer to the same object, and the all go out of scope.




















                       
`__gc` is called exactly once, (some time) after the last reference to that object is gone.

Comment: But wouldn't we always use the same function for `__close` and `__gc` 100% of the time (provided that we write that one single function carefully)? Is there any reason in Lua's design to bother having a second metamethod instead of just one?

Comment: You might want to close file handle in `__close` and release file buffer in `__gc`.  But it is more simple to create one function doing both this tasks and assign it to both metamethods.  But anyway `__close` might be invoked twice.

Comment: Another example: `__close` does not mean "destroy". You might want to close file handle ASAP (in `__close`) but keep working with file buffer accessing it using another variable (another reference to the same object).  Later when you finish working and remove all references to the object it will be destroyed in `__gc`.  In this example `__close` and `__gc` are semantically different.

Comment: You can also sequentially open (`local x <close> = x`) and close (in `__close`) the same object multiple times, and finally destroy it in `__gc`

Comment: @PromitheasNikou - `__gc is called exactly once` - It may be called 0 times if you exit with `os.exit()`.